# c++ sigabrt when pushing to vector of vectors

Tags: c++, algorithm, sigabrt

I am working on small program that is uses the Djikstra algorithm to search special paths in graphs. Algorithmically it is correct - I am 100% sure about that. Basically, the only modification to normal Djikstra is that when values of edges are pairs, they are compared in special way. Also, Djikstra returns 2 path lengths.

The task and details are not important here, because my program is failing due to something completely unrelated to it and I can`t seem to find why. It fails when reading input and putting it into structures.

The format of input goes as follows: n = number of vertices, m = number of edges and q = number of questions. Than m lines with description of edge: vertex1, vertex2, value, charValue that is either N or B. After that there are q questions asking about shortest path between start and end. I am getting

```
SIGABRT free(): invalid pointer: 0x000000000060b0d0
```

(the number of pointer is different all the time of course)
on push_back() on line 97 during working on last line of input when my input goes like this:

```
6 11 5
0 1 6 B
0 3 5 N
0 3 10 B
0 4 0 N
0 5 2 B
5 2 7 N
5 4 1 B
4 1 3 N
```

(the input is not finished - there are still some edges to go and also questions, but it fails at the same place all the time)

I tried Valgrind with no success. Code goes like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <limits>
#include <set>
using namespace std;

struct myStruct{
    long long n,b;
    int vertex; 
};

struct comparator {
    bool operator() (const myStruct& left, const myStruct& right) const{ 
        if (left.n == right.n ){
            return left.b < right.b;
        } else {
            return left.n < right.n;
        }
    }
};

pair<long long, long long> customDjikstra(int start, int end, int n,vector< vector< myStruct > > &graf){ //djikstra
    vector<pair<long long,long long> > djikstraLengthPaths; 
    set< myStruct , comparator > orderedSet;
    djikstraLengthPaths.reserve(n);
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        djikstraLengthPaths.push_back(make_pair(numeric_limits<long long>::max(),numeric_limits<long long>::max())); 
    }
    djikstraLengthPaths[start].first = 0;
    djikstraLengthPaths[start].second = 0;
    vector<bool> visited; 
    visited.resize(n);
    myStruct tmp,currentVertex;
    tmp.b = 0;
    tmp.n = 0;
    tmp.vertex = start;
    orderedSet.insert(tmp);

    while(!orderedSet.empty()){
        currentVertex = (*orderedSet.begin());
        orderedSet.erase(orderedSet.begin());
        if (visited[currentVertex.vertex]){
            continue;
        }
        visited[currentVertex.vertex] = true;

        for(int j = 0; j < graf[currentVertex.vertex].size();j++){
            myStruct edge = graf[currentVertex.vertex][j];

            if(djikstraLengthPaths[edge.vertex].first > currentVertex.n + edge.n || (djikstraLengthPaths[edge.vertex].first == currentVertex.n + edge.n && djikstraLengthPaths[edge.vertex].second > currentVertex.b + edge.b)){ //ak to zlepsi hodnotu nasej cesty, updatneme to
                djikstraLengthPaths[edge.vertex].first = currentVertex.n + edge.n;
                djikstraLengthPaths[edge.vertex].second = currentVertex.b + edge.n + edge.b;

                tmp.n = djikstraLengthPaths[edge.vertex].first;
                tmp.b = djikstraLengthPaths[edge.vertex].second;
                tmp.vertex = edge.vertex;
                orderedSet.insert(tmp);
            }
        }

    }

    return djikstraLengthPaths[end];

}

int main() {
    int n,m,q;
    cin >> n >> m >> q;
    vector<vector<myStruct> > graf(n); 
    myStruct temp;
    int a,b,c;
    char d;
    bool flag;
    for(int f = 0; f < m;f++){
        int i;
        cin >> a >> b >> c >> d;
        flag = 0;
        /*Graph is list of neighbours*/
        for(i = 0; i < graf[a].size();i++){
            if(graf[a][i].vertex == b){
                flag = 1;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(d == 'N'){

            if(!flag){
                temp.n = c;
                temp.b = 0;
                temp.vertex = b;
                graf[a].push_back(temp);
                temp.n = c;
                temp.b = 0;
                temp.vertex = a;
                graf[b].push_back(temp);
            } else if(graf[a][i].n > c) {
                graf[a][i].n = c;
                graf[a][i].b = 0;
                graf[b][i].n = c;
                graf[b][i].b = 0;
            }

        }else {
            if(!flag){
                temp.n = 0;
                temp.b = c;
                temp.vertex = b;
                graf[a].push_back(temp);
                temp.n = 0;
                temp.b = c;
                temp.vertex = a;
                graf[b].push_back(temp);
            } else if(graf[a][i].n > 0 || graf[a][i].b > c) {
                graf[a][i].n = 0;
                graf[a][i].b = c;

                graf[b][i].n = 0;
                graf[b][i].b = c;

            }
        }
    }

    int start,end;
    pair<long long, long long> answer;

    for(int j = 0; j < q;j++){
        cin >> start >> end;
        answer = customDjikstra(start,end,n,graf);
        if(answer.first == numeric_limits<long long>::max()){ 
            cout << "-1 -1" << endl;
        } else {
            cout << answer.first << ' ' << answer.second << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

If you could help me and tell me what am I doing wrong, forgetting to initialise or anything like that, it would be great.

Comment: With an excerpt of this length, can you include line numbers or visually indicate line 97? People will be reluctant to count them or extract the code into an external editor.

Comment: Anyway, my suspicion is that somewhere in here, an iterator is being invalidated, due to all the iterators and loops going on. I'll try to look closer...

Comment: I'm not going to begin to dissect the root cause, but in the else-case of your `if(d == 'N')` conditional, the accessor for `graf[b][i]`  (used twice) is exceeding your boundaries. The specific repeatable case i'm seeing is where `b == 3` and `i == 1`. At that time, the `graf[b]` sub-vector has only one item in it, thus it is indexible only by `0`.

Comment: Well, I just found out, that my comparator can be a problem during set operations, because it is not letting some structs go into set propertly, but it still doesn't explain this input error

Comment: @WhozCraig well, yes, that looks like it. I am checking only the first vector and they are separate and so can be different lengths. That should be it. Thanks a lot

Comment: @fifco Glad it... helped =P. Btw, can't your comparator just be something like `return std::make_tuple(left.n, left.b) < std::make_tuple(right.n, right.b);` ?

Comment: there is a problem with it that it doesn't return a<b || a>b all the time. For instance (1,2,5) == (1,2,8) for w=5 and w=8 and so it doesn't allow insertion of second one into set

Comment: @fifco I would suggest you change from using `[ ]` to access vector elements and instead use `vector::at()`.  Using this will throw an `out_of_range` exception with much more information if you are going beyond the boundaries of the vector.  That is much better than a crash with no further information.   Second, you should give your variables more descriptive names.  Naming variables `a`, `b`, `n`, etc. not only makes it hard to figure the code out, you could at some point conceivably hide those 1 letter variable names with local variables, and not know you made the mistake.

Comment: @fifco Also, what is the test data you're using?  If you gave us the input you're using to duplicate the error, that would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
int main() {
int n,m,q;
cin >> n >> m >> q;
vector<vector<myStruct> > graf(n); 
myStruct temp;
int a,b,c;
char d;
bool flag;
for(int f = 0; f < m;f++){
    int i;
    cin >> a >> b >> c >> d;
    flag = 0;
    /*Graph is list of neighbours*/
    for(i = 0; i < graf[a].size();i++){
        if(graf[a][i].vertex == b){
            flag = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
```

you do not resize the inner vectors in graf `if(graf[a][i].vertex == b)`
you are out of bounds. You need to resize the inner vector to the correct length like

```
for(int i =0;i<n;i++)
{
  graf[i].resize(size_var);
}
```